# Copy symlinks from ext3 to cifs share

Tags: linux, scp

I'm using `scp` to copy files from a Linux disk (ext3 file format) to a Windows disk (NTFS exposed using CIFS over the network). I've found that `scp` follows symbolic links and copies their contents instead of copying the symbolic link. I wish to instead copy the link itself.

Is there a way to do this? I don't have to use `scp`, other copy methods are acceptable, as long as it can be copied over a network.

Answer (score 2):

If the CIFS exported disk is mounted on your Linux box, there is no need to use `scp`. You can use 'cp -d source destination'. From `man cp`

```
-d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=links

--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
       preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,time‐
       stamps),  if  possible  additional  attributes:  context, links,
       xattr, all

-P, --no-dereference
       never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
```

I am not sure however if it is meaningful or possible to store soft-links on NTFS and whether you can copy those back. If I recall correctly NTFS only had some sort of hard-link, but it has been quite a few years since I looked at that.

If you don't need access to the files directly (more like a backup) you can store the whole (files and links) as a tar file.